# scheduling jobs using spring batch or just Quartz scheduler

Tags: spring, queue, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I am looking for best solution to create a java web application to generate reports in excel/PDf format. some thing similar to Google Adwords, where user can  create schedule reports and download it when the report is generated at a later time.

I am thinking to develop and java application where User logs, selects a pre defined report and provides the input parameters (like report  date etc), This request will be queued up or saved as Quarts Job(prefer persistent Queue). A Job will be monitoring the queue/job and execute the job, generate the report(output excel /pdf) and stored in disk.
When the user refresh the screen or logs back at a later time, the report should be available for down load.

Using  Spring batch and Quartz scheduler can I do this ?  I also expecting like Spring admin , where I can see number of request in Queue(jobs queued up), and stop the queue processing etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use spring-batch if you wanted to process all report requests at the same time, perhaps at night when your servers are not otherwise occupied processing real-time user requests (or even during the day during slow periods).

You would use a quartz job if you wanted to check for new jobs every few seconds/minutes/hours/etc, and process one/many of them at that specified time interval.

So, quartz is a scheduler and batch is a process. You could use quartz to schedule batch jobs to run at specific times. They aren't competing technologies, they are complimentary.

**About your question:**
Given that you talk about queues and their persistence however it sounds a lot like your problem would fit into a simple jms model. You would need some messaging software. If you want to make it easy on yourself I'd recommend using [spring-jms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html) as a wrapper around the basic Java EE JMS api -- the spring wrappers are simply simpler than basic jms. For a messaging service I'd look at [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), because again it's pretty simple.

With the jms architecture you'd post user requests to the queue, which you'd configured to be persistent. You'd have a custom listener on the queue, passing requests to a report generator whenever it runs. You can assign one or more threads to the listener, meaning that you should find it easy to tune the performance of the report generator.

There is a pretty useful [DZone article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/bridging-between-jms-and) about using rabbitmq via [spring-integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) (a set of prebuilt pattern implementations that help with connecting things to each other).

Comment: The difference is not at all clear in the answer, can you please explain exactly the first two statements.